# $controller:ctrlreg error when my Angular code is loaded from our CDN

Tags: angularjs, cdn

Getting a Error: $controller:ctrlreg error when my Angular code is loaded from our CDN.

However, when I load the same Angular, from a local server, everything works.

We are using gulp to concat, minify and rev all our angular code.

I have checked the actual js file that loads in the browser and I see my controller.

Any ideas?

The error is:

> all.js:258 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=accountController

Here is my controller.

```
(function(){

'use strict';

angular.module('account')
.controller('accountController', [accountController]);

function accountController(){

}
})();
```

This is my html

```
<div ng-controller="accountController as ctrl">

</div>
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: check error in console..? and post them here.. also add relevant code

Comment: did it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being a cacheing issue in CloudFront.  The JS file that was getting downloaded on my sandbox was not updating in the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a empty dependency to your module, change it as

```
angular.module('account',[])
.controller('accountController', [accountController]);
```